# Can I put new values in array inide foreach?

Tags: php

I have a foreach loop, in which I loop through the array. I want to add elements as I go through it and have new ones go through it as well.

Now with this code it only does the iterations that I have in the array at the beginning (1 in this case).

Can somebody help me

Thanks

```
 public static function getDirectoriesChilds($id_parent, $parents_array) {
    $session_client = Client::getSessionClient();
    array_push($parents_array, $id_parent);
    $parents_array = array_unique($parents_array);
    foreach ($parents_array as $element) {
        $childs = Directory::where('id_parent' , '=', $element)->get();
        foreach ($childs as $child) {
            if ($child->deleted == Controller::DISABLED) {
                array_push($parents_array, $child->id);
                $parents_array = array_unique($parents_array);
            }
        }
        
    }
    return $parents_array;
}
```

Comment: Foreach will iterate over the array it's given. It will not check if you add to the array inside the loop. In other news, your code would be much more economical if you ran your array_unique only once at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If changes foreach to for works.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($parents_array); $i++){
```